# Python: Writing quite complicated piece of code as a List Comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, dynamic-programming

I have solved the [Word Break](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) problem with the following code:

```
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        n = len(s)
        dp = [False] * n
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
                if (s[i : j] in wordDict) and (i == 0 or dp[i - 1]):
                    dp[j - 1] = True
        return dp[n - 1]
```

And I'm trying to write it as a list comprehension to make it "more or less one-line code".

I have been trying to express `dp` as follows:

```
dp = [True if (s[i:j] in wordDict) and (i==0 or dp[i-1]) for j in range(i+1, n+1) for i in range(n) else False]
```

However, I kind of got stuck because in the original code it is set `dp[j - 1] = True` while I couldn't make it with a list comprehension.

I know it's not a good idea to write a big piece of code as a list comprehension (I'm confused already too) but it is just for **educational purposes**.

Comment: Can you provide the sample input you are providing to the code? It's not exactly clear what your code does.

Comment: @AmitSingh added a link to the problem.

Comment: The primary requirement for list comprehension is having access to an iterable so unless you convert it to an iterable somehow, it'll be difficult to achieve what you want to do with your correct approach. So, we would have to rewrite the part where you might change value of `d[j-1]` multiple times.

Comment: As is, this can not be rewritten as a list comprehension, since you refer to `dp[i - 1]` inside the loop. As a list comprehension, the variable `dp` would not even be declared at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as `dp` is written to, and not only that, but those freshly written values are *read* again in next iterations, this would not be a candidate for list comprehension.
If however you are willing to sacrifice some best practices in Python, you can get close.

First, you *can* turn the inner loop into a list comprehension:

```
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
    n = len(s)
    dp = [False] * n
    for i in range(n):
        dp[i:] = [dp[j] or
                   (s[i:j+1] in wordDict) and (i == 0 or dp[i-1])
                   for j in range(i, n)]
    return dp[-1]
```

Let's slightly change the algorithm, so the list overwriting happens from index 0, and not from index i. Instead we shorten the list gradually. At the same time we designate `dp[0]` as the value to read from the previous iteration, so we also prefix it to the initial list:

```
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
    n = len(s)
    dp = [True] + [False] * n
    for i in range(n):
        dp = [dp[j-i+1] or s[i:j+1] in wordDict and dp[0]
                   for j in range(i, n)]
    return dp[0]
```

But `dp =`  is an assignment that in principle blocks a wider use of list comprehension.
You can get around this with a a-Pythonic function, which both alters and returns something:

```
def assign(self, target, source):
    target[:] = source  # mutate the target
    return target[-1]  # for our purposes we only need it to return the last value
```

And now we can include it in a larger list comprehension expression:

```
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
    n = len(s)
    dp = [True] + [False] * n
    return [
        self.assign(dp, [dp[j-i+1] or s[i:j+1] in wordDict and dp[0]
                        for j in range(i, n)])
                        for i in range(n)
    ][-1]
```

But to repeat: this is not pythonic. It is best practice to let a function *either* mutate an argument (or `self`), *or* return a value, but not both. There are only a few exceptions to this rule (e.g. `.pop()`)

If instead of list comprehension, you are happy with a functional expression, an alternative could be to use `functools.reduce`:

```
def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
    n = len(s)
    return reduce(lambda dp, i: [dp[j-i+1] or s[i:j+1] in wordDict and dp[0]
                                 for j in range(i, n)], 
                  range(n), 
                  [True] + [False] * n)[0]
```